# WPF Telerik Scatter Point colors

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, telerik

I am beginner in WPF telerik technology framework.
I want custom colors to points in telerik scatter point chart. But colors of points are not changing. What should I do? Is there something fundamentally wrong in what I am doing?
Here is c# code

```
    var pallate = ColorPallate();

    var PS = new ScatterPointSeries();

    var pallaet = new ChartPalette();

    PaletteEntryCollection pall = new PaletteEntryCollection();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.GetLength(0); i++)

    {

        ScatterDataPoint point = new ScatterDataPoint();

        point.XValue = data[i, XAxisIndex];

        point.YValue = data[i, YAaxisIndex];

        int value = 0;

        if (!float.IsNaN(PredictedResult[i]))

            value = System.Convert.ToInt32(PredictedResult[i]);

        var filler = new PaletteEntry();
        filler.fill(pallate[value]);
        pall.Add(filler);
        PS.DataPoints.Add(point);



    }

    pallaet.SeriesEntries.Add(pall);

    this.Cross_Plot.Palette = pallaet;
```

Where ColorPallate() provide custom color palatte as

```
private Brush[] ColorPallate()

{



    var pallate = new Brush[15];

    pallate[0] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

    pallate[1] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);

    pallate[2] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);

    pallate[3] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Pink);

    pallate[4] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

    pallate[5] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Brown);

    pallate[6] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Crimson);

    pallate[7] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkOrange);

    pallate[8] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.ForestGreen);

    pallate[9] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Indigo);

    pallate[10] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkKhaki);

    pallate[11] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Purple);

    pallate[12] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gold);

    pallate[13] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.RosyBrown);

    pallate[14] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);

    return pallate;

}
```

Here is XMAL code

```
            <telerik:RadCartesianChart x:Name="Cross_Plot" Margin="0,51,17,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="472" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="1057" Grid.RowSpan="2" >

                



                <telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>

                    <telerik:LinearAxis SmartLabelsMode="SmartStep"  MajorTickOffset="0"/>

                </telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>



                <telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>

                    <telerik:LinearAxis SmartLabelsMode="SmartStep"  ElementBrush="Black" />

                </telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>



                <telerik:ScatterPointSeries XValueBinding="XValue"  YValueBinding="YValue" ItemsSource="{Binding}">

                    <telerik:ScatterPointSeries.DefaultVisualStyle>

                        <Style TargetType="Path">

                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Tag.DataItem.Color}" />

                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="10" />

                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="10" />

                        </Style>

                    </telerik:ScatterPointSeries.DefaultVisualStyle>

                </telerik:ScatterPointSeries>







            </telerik:RadCartesianChart>



            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="131,37,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Well points on X Axis" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="248"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="389,35,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Well points on Y axis" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="243"/>
```

I shall be very thankful to you for your efforts

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Telerik docs? https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radchartview/features/palettes/custom-palettes

Comment: Yup, but I am looking for dynamic (run time data dependent c# )code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Telerik's [PointTemplateSelector](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radchartview/styles-and-templates/customizing-scatter-points). This allows each point to be customized dynamically in code.

[image]